# Bubble sort isn't sorting properly

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

So, in my program, I am trying to take an array filled with random numbers and sort them using bubble sort. When I run my program I can clearly see the randomly generated numbers before the sorting begins, but after I run my bubbleSort method, the numbers are all 0's.

I'm sure there is something small I am overlooking but this is driving me crazy! Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class partThree {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    int max = 1000;

    System.out.println("How many items are in the array? ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int array[] = new int[n];

    System.out.println("How many times should the loop be iterated? ");
    int num_i = scan.nextInt();

    rand.nextInt(max);

    for(int i=0; i<num_i; i++)
        array[i] = rand.nextInt(max);

    System.out.println("Before sorting: ");
    for(int i=0; i<num_i; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

    bubbleSort(array);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("After sorting: ");
    for(int i=0; i<num_i; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

}

public static void bubbleSort(int[] array){

    int n = array.length;
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){

            if(array[j-1] > array[j]){
                temp = array[j-1];
                array[j-1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: If you think any of the answers below are right, please mark them as answers or up vote them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ask for 2 inputs, the same input must be used for sizing the array and filling it.

In your current example, if I input 2 different values, say 10 then 5, I'll end up with 5 zeros in the array (0 is the default int value).

Your sort algorithm looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your num_i is effectively the size of the array.
It is not the number of iterations.

```
int array[] = new int[n];
```

or

```
int array[] = new int[num_i];
```

Using both and n and num_i is not write. You should populate you array completely with random number.

Answer (score 0):

This is not required:

```
 System.out.println("How many times should the loop be iterated? ");
```

In fact, num_i is redundant. Once you specify that there are 'n' elements, let random number generator fill 'n' random values.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        array[i] = rand.nextInt(max);
```